# global name is not defined when importing other python file

Tags: python

I have two files, *blah.py* and *couch.py*. I'm trying to use a function from *couch.py* in *blah.py*, so I put `import couch` at the top of blah.py.

When I try using that function from couch, I get:

> global name 'function' is not defined

I made sure that they're in the same directory and was just wondering why this happens?

Comment: `couch.function` or `from couch import function`

Comment: Please add [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call function as `couch.function_name()`

or you can import it as `from couch import function_name`